# The group of invertible fractional ideals of a Noetherian domain of dimension 1

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a Noetherian domain of dimension 1.
Let $I(A)$ be the group of [invertible fractional ideals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_ideal) of $A$.
Let $P$ be a maximal ideal of $A$.
Let $I(A_P)$ be the group of invertible fractional ideals of $A_P$.
Let $I$ be an invertible fractional ideal of $A$.
$IA_P$ is an invertible fractional ideal of $A_P$.
It's easy to see that $IA_P = A_P$ except for finitely many $P$s.
Hence we get a homomorphism $f\colon I(A) \rightarrow \bigoplus_P I(A_P)$, where $P$ runs over all the maximal ideals of $A$. I need to prove that $f$ is an isomorphism. So my question is: Is $f$ an isomorphism?

Perhaps this question is a special case of Proposition (21.9.4) of [EGA IV-4](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=PMIHES_1967__32__5_0), p.285.
But I think it's desirable to have a direct proof.

This question is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158876/ideal-class-group-of-a-one-dimensional-noetherian-domain).

**EDIT**[Jul 3, 2012]
**Martin Brandenburg** Nothing new? Perhaps you are right(this is not MathOverflow), but I hadn't known the proof. Could you please show us your proof or the reference?

**EDIT**
It is well-known that an invertible fractional ideals of a semilocal domain is principal(see Bourbaki, Algebre Commutative, Chapitre II $\S$ 5, or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162679/a-characterization-of-invertible-fractional-ideals-of-an-integral-domain) for a local domain).
Hence $I(A_P)$ is the group of prinicipal fractional ideals of $A_P$.

**EDIT**[Jun/25/2012]
Since there has been no answer so far, I'll try to prove the above result.
I need several lemmas most of which are well-known, but I will prove them for the readers' convenience.

**Lemma 1**
Let $A$ be a commutative ring.
Let $S$ be a multiplicative subset of $A$.
Let $M$ be an $A$-module.
Let $N$ and $L$ be $A$-submodules of $M$.
Then $(N \cap L)_S = N_S \cap L_S$ as submodules of $M_S$.

Proof:
The following sequence is exact.
$0 \rightarrow N \cap L \rightarrow M \rightarrow M/N \oplus M/L$

Hence we get an exact sequence:
$0 \rightarrow (N \cap L)_S \rightarrow M_S \rightarrow M_S/N_S \oplus M_S/L_S$

Hence $(N \cap L)_S = N_S \cap L_S$
**QED**

**Lemma 2**
Let $A$ be a Noetherian commutative ring.
Let $\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathfrak{q}$ be prime ideals of $A$.
Suppose $\mathfrak{q}$ is not contained $\mathfrak{p}$.
Let $\mathfrak{Q}$ be a $\mathfrak{q}$-primary ideal.
Then $\mathfrak{Q}A_\mathfrak{p} = A_\mathfrak{p}$.

Proof:
There exists $n \gt 0$ such that $\mathfrak{q}^n \subset \mathfrak{Q}$.
Since $\mathfrak{q}$ is not contained $\mathfrak{p}$,
$\mathfrak{q}A_\mathfrak{p} = A_\mathfrak{p}$.
Hence $\mathfrak{q}^nA_\mathfrak{p} = A_\mathfrak{p}$.
Hence $\mathfrak{Q}A_\mathfrak{p} = A_\mathfrak{p}$.
**QED**

**Lemma 3**
Let $A$ be a Noetherian commutative ring.
Let $\mathfrak{m}_1, ..., \mathfrak{m}_n$ be distinct maximal ideals of $A$.
For each $i$, let $\mathfrak{q}_i$ be an ($\mathfrak{m}_iA_{\mathfrak{m}_i}$)-primary ideal of $A_{\mathfrak{m}_i}$.
Let $\mathfrak{Q}_i$ be the inverse image of $\mathfrak{q}_i$ by the canonical homomorphism $A \rightarrow A_{\mathfrak{m}_i}$.
Let $I = \mathfrak{Q}_1 \cap ... \cap \mathfrak{Q}_n$.
Then $IA_{\mathfrak{m}_i} = \mathfrak{q}_i$ for each $i$.

Proof:
By **Lemma 1**,
$IA_{\mathfrak{m}_i} = \mathfrak{Q}_1A_{\mathfrak{m}_i} \cap ... \cap \mathfrak{Q}_nA_{\mathfrak{m}_i}$.
By **Lemma 2**, $\mathfrak{Q}_jA_{\mathfrak{m}_i} = A_{\mathfrak{m}_i}$ for $i \neq j$.
Hence $IA_{\mathfrak{m}_i} = \mathfrak{Q}_iA_{\mathfrak{m}_i} = \mathfrak{q}_i$.
**QED**

**Lemma 4**
Let $A$ be a commutative ring. Let $M$ be an $A$-module.
Let $N$ and $L$ be $A$-submodules of $M$.
Suppose $N_\mathfrak{m} = L_\mathfrak{m}$ for every maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $A$.
Then $N = L$.

Proof:
Let $x \in N$.
Let $I = \{a \in A; ax \in L\}$.
Suppose $I \neq A$.
Then there exist a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ such that $I \subset \mathfrak{m}$.
Since $x/1 ∈ N_\mathfrak{m} = L_\mathfrak{m}$, there exists $s \in A - \mathfrak{m}$ such that $sx \in L$.
Hence $s \in I$.
This is a contradiction.
Hence $I = A$.
Hence $x \in L$.
Therefore $N \subset L$.
Similarly $L \subset N$.
**QED**

**Lemma 5**[this lemma is unnecessary, but I leave it here]
Let $A$ be an integral domain.
Let $K$ be its field of fractions.
Then $A = \cap A_\mathfrak{m}$, where $\mathfrak{m}$ runs over all the maximal ideals of $A$ and each $A_\mathfrak{m}$ is regarded as a subring of $K$.

Proof:
Let x $\in \cap A_\mathfrak{m}$.
Let $I = \{a \in A; ax \in A\}$.
Suppose $I \neq A$.
Then there exists a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ such that $I \subset \mathfrak{m}$.
Since $x/1 \in A_\mathfrak{m}$, there exists $s \in A - \mathfrak{m}$
such that $sx \in A$.
Hence $s \in I$.
This is a contradiction.
Hence $I = A$.
Hence $x \in A$.
Therefore $\cap A_\mathfrak{m} \subset A$.
The other inclusion is clear.
**QED**

**Proposition 1**
Let $A$ be a Noetherian domain of dimension 1.
The above homomorphism $f\colon I(A) \rightarrow \bigoplus_P I(A_P)$ is injective.

Proof:
Let $K$ be the field of fractions of $A$.
Let $M$ be an invertible fractional ideal of $A$.
Suppose $f(M) = 0$.
Hence $M_P = A_P$ for all the maximal ideals $P$ of $A$.
Since $M$ and $A$ are $A$-submodules of $K$, by **Lemma 4**, $M = A$.
**QED**

**Proposition 2**
Let $A$ be a Noetherian domain of dimension 1.
The above homomorphism $f\colon I(A) \rightarrow \bigoplus_P I(A_P)$ is surjective.

Proof:
Let $x = (x_P)$ be an element of $\bigoplus_P I(A_P)$.
Since $I(A_P)$ is the group of principal ideals of $A_P$ for each P, $x_P = (a_P/b_P)A_P$ for some $a_P, b_P \in A$.
$(a_P/b_P)A_P = A_P$ for all but finitely many $Ps$.
If $(a_P/b_P)A_P = A_P$, we can assume $a_P = b_P = 1$.
For each $P$, let $I(P) = A \cap a_PA_P$.
If $a_PA_P \neq A_P$, $a_PA_P$ is $(PA_P)$-primary ideal.
Let $I = \cap I(P)$.
By **Lemma 3**, $IA_P = a_PA_P$ for all $P$.
Since $I$ is locally principal, $I$ is invertible(see Bourbaki, Algebre Commutative, Chapitre II $\S$ 5).
Similarly, for each $P$, let $J(P) = A \cap b_PA_P$.
Let $J = \cap J(P)$.
Since $J$ is locally principal, $J$ is invertible.
Let $M = IJ^{-1}$.
Then $M_P = (a_P/b_P)A_P$ for each $P$.
Hence $f$ is surjective.
**QED**

Comment: Erm, this seems to be an excerpt from a commutative algebra textbook. Nothing new. And where is the question?!

Comment: @MakotoKato, if you think you have a proof, you should consider posting it as an answer to your question. There is nothing wrong with answering your own question (and even accepting that answer). If you think there is a gap in your proposed proof (and I don't see one), you should make it clear what you are worried about. Also, in case you don't know, "\bigoplus" is the tex command for $\bigoplus$, the standard notation for direct sum (rather than $\sum$, which I don't think is used enough to have a standard meaning, but I normally see it used to mean something different than "direct sum").

Comment: @BR Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @MakotoKato, also, "\oplus" gives the smaller version $\oplus$ when you want to write $A\oplus B$, instead of $\bigoplus_p A_p$.

Comment: @BR Thanks, again.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Nothing new? Then I suppose you know this problem very well. Can I see your answer to my question?