# A lemma on the integral closure of a Noetherian domain of dimension 1

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I need to prove the following lemma(?) which is motivated by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158876/ideal-class-group-of-a-one-dimensional-noetherian-domain) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159699/the-group-of-invertible-fractional-ideals-of-a-noetherian-domain-of-dimension-1).

**Lemma**
Let $A$ be a Noetherian domain of dimension 1.
Let $K$ be the field of fractions of $A$.
Let $B$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $K$.
Suppose $B$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module.
Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a maximal ideal of $A$.
Let $B_{\mathfrak{p}}$ be the localization of B with respect to the multiplicative subset $A - \mathfrak{p}$.
Then $K^*/(B_{\mathfrak{p}})^*$ is isomorphic to $\bigoplus K^*/(B_{\mathfrak{P}})^*$, where  $\mathfrak{P}$ runs over all the maximal ideals of $B$ lying over $\mathfrak{p}$.

**EDIT**[Jun 26, 2012]
Using this lemma, we can prove the following result.

**Proposition**
Let $A$ be a Noetherian domain of dimension 1.
Let $K$ be the field of fractions of $A$.
Let $B$ be the integral closure of $A$ in $K$.
Suppose $B$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module.
Let $I(B)$ be the group of invertible fractional ideals of $B$.
Then $I(B)$ is canonically isomorphisc to $\bigoplus_{\mathfrak{p}} K^*/(B_{\mathfrak{p}})^*$.
Here, $\mathfrak{p}$ runs on all the maximal ideals of $A$.

Proof:
Since $B$ is a Noetherian domain of dimension 1,
by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159699/the-group-of-invertible-fractional-ideals-of-a-noetherian-domain-of-dimension-1), $I(B)$ is canonically isomorphisc to
$\bigoplus_{\mathfrak{P}} I(B_{\mathfrak{P}})$, where ${\mathfrak{P}}$ runs over all the maximal ideals of $B$. 
Since $B_{\mathfrak{P}}$ is a local domain, by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162679/a-characterization-of-invertible-fractional-ideals-of-an-integral-domain), $I(B_{\mathfrak{P}})$ is the group of principal fractional ideals of $B_{\mathfrak{P}}$.
Hence $I(B_{\mathfrak{P}})$ is canonically isomorphic to $K^*/(B_{\mathfrak{P}})^*$.
Hence $I(B)$ is canonically isomorphisc to $\bigoplus_{\mathfrak{P}} K^*/(B_{\mathfrak{P}})^*$.
Hence by the above lemma, $I(B)$ is canonically isomorphisc to $\bigoplus_{\mathfrak{p}} K^*/(B_{\mathfrak{p}})^*$.
**QED**

Answer (score 2):

Since $B_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is an integrally closed Noetherian domain of dimension 1, it is a Dedekind domain.
Since it has only finitely many maximal ideals, it is a PID.
Let $R = B_{\mathfrak{p}}$.
By [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159699/the-group-of-invertible-fractional-ideals-of-a-noetherian-domain-of-dimension-1), $K^*/R^*$ is canonically isomorphic to $\bigoplus_M K^*/(R_M)^*$,
where $M$ runs on all the mximal ideals of $R$.
Since $M$ is of a form $\mathfrak{P}R$, where $\mathfrak{P}$ is a maximal ideal of $B$ lying over $\mathfrak{p}$, $R_M$ is canonically isomorphic to $B_{\mathfrak{P}}$