# Prime ideal $P$ in $R$ coprime to the conductor plus the localization $R_{P}$ is a DVR implies that $P$ is invertible

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, dedekind-domain

I have the following situation:

Let $B \subseteq B'$ be a ring extension such that $\text{Quot}(B) = \text{Quot}(B') =: K$ and $\text{dim}(B) = \text{dim}(B') = 1$ where $B'$ is a Dedekind domain. Let $\mathcal{F} = \{ x \in K \mid xB' \subseteq B \}$ be the conductor of $B$ in $B'$.

Now I want to show that every prime ideal $P$ in $B$ coprime to $\mathcal{F}$, i.e. $P + \mathcal{F} = B$, is invertible.

We have already proven that *those prime ideals $P$ coprime to the conductor satisfy that the localization $B_{P}$ is a discrete valuation ring.* $(*)$

The source states that the desired proposition follows from $(*)$.

**My thoughts:**

From [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162679/a-characterization-of-invertible-fractional-ideals-of-an-integral-domain) we have:

**Proposition:** $M$ as a fractional ideal is invertible if and only if $MB_{P}$ is a principal fractional ideal for every maximal ideal $P$ of $B$.

In my situation we have $B_{P}$ is a DVR, hence a local PID und therefore $PB_{P}$ is a principal ideal and clearly invertible as a fractional ideal of $B_{P}$. From $\text{dim}(B) = 1$ we have that every prime ideal $\neq 0$ is maximal, but I don't know how to go on and use the fact that $P + \mathcal{F} = B$.

I'd appreciate any kind of help and input.

Comment: You must be have already used that $P + \mathcal{F} = B$ since you proved that $B_P$ is a DVR. (Now I hope you can understand my previous comment better.)

Comment: The source is part of some lecture notes from my professor and therefore I wasn't sure if I'm allowed to put that here; besides it's written in german.
And yes, $P + \mathcal{F} = B$ was used to show that $B_P$ is a DVR. Again, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use the invertibility criterion you mentioned (changing the notation):

> $I$ is invertible iff $IB_Q$ is a principal fractional ideal for every maximal ideal $Q$ of $B$.

Since $\dim B=1$ there is no maximal ideal containing $P$ excepting $P$ itself (of course, the trivial case $P=(0)$ can be excepted), so $PB_Q=B_Q$ for all $Q\ne P$. Is it clear now?

Comment: I thought about this before but I kind of scrapped that idea for no reason. Of course this is the answer, it's clear now! Thank you very much.