# Norm of the product of two regular ideals of an order of an algebraic number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, alternative-proof

Let $K$ be an algebraic number field of degree $n$.
Let $\mathcal{O}_K$ be the ring of algebraic integers.
An order of $K$ is a subring $R$ of $K$ such that $R$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank $n$.
I am interested in the ideal theory on $R$ because when $n = 2$ it has a deep connection with the theory of binary quadratic forms as shown in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192217/bijection-between-an-ideal-class-group-and-a-set-of-classes-of-binary-quadratic). 
Let $I$ be a non-zero ideal of $R$.
It is easy to see that $R/I$ is a finite ring.
The number of elements of $R/I$ is called the norm of $I$ and is denoted by $N(I)$.
Let $\mathfrak{f} = \{x \in R | x\mathcal{O}_K \subset R\}$.
If $I + \mathfrak{f} = R$, we call $I$ regular.
Properties of regular ideals are stated in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158876/ideal-class-group-of-a-one-dimensional-noetherian-domain).
Let $I, J$ be regular ideals of $R$.
If $R = \mathcal{O}_K$, it is well-known that $N(IJ) = N(I)N(J)$.
I wondered if this holds when $R \ne \mathcal{O}_K$.
And I came up with the following proposition.

**Proposition**
Let $I, J$ be regular ideals of $R$.
Then $N(IJ) = N(I)N(J)$.

**Outline of my proof**
I used the result of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555379/factor-ring-by-a-regular-ideal-of-a-one-dimensional-noetherian-domain) and reduced the problem to the case $R = \mathcal{O}_K$.

**My question**
How do you prove the proposition?
I would like to know other proofs based on different ideas from mine.
I welcome you to provide as many different proofs as possible.
I wish the proofs would be detailed enough for people who have basic knowledge of introductory algebraic number theory to be able to understand.

**Related question**
A generalization of this question is asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557548/on-the-norm-formula-nij-ninj-in-an-order-of-an-algebraic-number-field).

Comment: I think you're supposed to put the answer in the answer box, and save the meta for meta.

Comment: The spoiler shows how I tried to solve the problem. When you post a question, You need to show your effort to solve it.

Comment: I opened the following meta thread asking why this question was put on hold.
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11617/why-was-this-question-norm-of-the-product-of-two-regular-ideals-of-an-order-of

Answer (score 2):

By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555379/factor-ring-by-a-regular-ideal-of-a-one-dimensional-noetherian-domain), $N(I) = N(I\mathcal{O}_K), N(J) = N(J\mathcal{O}_K), N(IJ) = N(IJ\mathcal{O}_K)$. Hence $N(IJ) = N(I\mathcal{O}_K)N(J\mathcal{O}_K) = N(I)N(J)$.