# Norm of a regular ideal of an order of an algebraic number field which is Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, alternative-proof

Let $K$ be an algebraic number field of degree $n$.
Let $\mathcal{O}_K$ be the ring of algebraic integers.
An order of $K$ is a subring $R$ of $K$ such that $R$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank $n$.
I am interested in the ideal theory on $R$ because it is closely related to the theory of binary quadratic forms when $n = 2$ as shown in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192217/bijection-between-an-ideal-class-group-and-a-set-of-classes-of-binary-quadratic). 
Let $I$ be a non-zero ideal of $R$.
We denote by $N(I)$ the number of elements of the finite ring $R/I$.
Let $\mathfrak{f} = \{x \in R | x\mathcal{O}_K \subset R\}$.
If $I + \mathfrak{f} = R$, we call $I$ regular.
For the properties of regular ideals, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158876/ideal-class-group-of-a-one-dimensional-noetherian-domain).

**My question**
Is the following Proposition correct? If yes, how do you prove it?

**Proposition**
Let $K$ be an algebraic number field of degree $n$ such that $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois.
Let $G$ be the Galois group of $K/\mathbb{Q}$.
Let $R$ be an order of $K$ such that $\sigma(R) = R$ for every $\sigma \in G$.
Let $I$ be a regular ideal of $R$.
Then $\prod_{\sigma\in G} \sigma(I) = N(I)R$.

**Remark**
I am not sure of the correctness of the proposition, though I think it is likely to be true(see my method below). I would like to know if I am on the right track.
I also would like to know as many different proofs of the proposition as possible if it is correct.
When you post an answer, please provide a full proof which can be understood by people who have basic knowledge of introductory algebraic number theory.

**My method**
Use the results of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158876/ideal-class-group-of-a-one-dimensional-noetherian-domain) and reduce the problem to the case $R = \mathcal{O}_K$.

Comment: This seems likely. It is fairly well-known, for example, that $\displaystyle \prod_{\sigma \in G}\sigma(I)\cap\mathbb{Z}=N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(I)$. Thus, we have the obvious containment $N(I)R\subseteq\prod_{\sigma}\sigma(I)$, and I think by checking indices that cardinalities force equality.

Answer (score 1):

We first show that $\mathfrak{f}$ is $G$-invariant, i.e. $\sigma(\mathfrak{f}) = \mathfrak{f}$
for every $\sigma \in G$.
It suffices to prove that $\sigma(\mathfrak{f}) \subset \mathfrak{f}$ for every $\sigma \in G$.
Let $x \in \mathfrak{f}$.
Since $x\mathcal{O}_K \subset R, \sigma(x)\mathcal{O}_K \subset \sigma(R) = R$.
Hence $\sigma(x) \in \mathfrak{f}$ as desired.

Let $a = N(I)$.
Let $J = \prod_{\sigma\in G} \sigma(I)$.
Since $I + \mathfrak{f} = R$, $\sigma(I) + \sigma(\mathfrak{f}) = \sigma(R)$ for every $\sigma \in G$.
Since $\sigma(\mathfrak{f}) = \mathfrak{f}$ and $\sigma(R) = R$, $\sigma(I)$ is regular.
Hence $J$ is regular.

By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555379/factor-ring-by-a-regular-ideal-of-a-one-dimensional-noetherian-domain), $a = N(I\mathcal{O}_K)$.
It is well-known that $\prod_{\sigma\in G} \sigma(I\mathcal{O}_K) = a\mathcal{O}_K$.
Since $J\mathcal{O}_K = \prod_{\sigma\in G} \sigma(I\mathcal{O}_K)$, 
$J\mathcal{O}_K = a\mathcal{O}_K$.
By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158876/ideal-class-group-of-a-one-dimensional-noetherian-domain), $J\mathcal{O}_K \cap R = J$.

Hence it suffices to prove that $a\mathcal{O}_K \cap R = aR$.
Since $\sigma(I)\mathcal{O}_K + \mathfrak{f} = \mathcal{O}_K$ for every $\sigma \in G$,
$a\mathcal{O}_K + \mathfrak{f} = \mathcal{O}_K$.
Hence by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158876/ideal-class-group-of-a-one-dimensional-noetherian-domain), $a\mathcal{O}_K \cap R$ is regular and 
$(a\mathcal{O}_K \cap R)\mathcal{O}_K = a\mathcal{O}_K$.
By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/555379/factor-ring-by-a-regular-ideal-of-a-one-dimensional-noetherian-domain), $N(a\mathcal{O}_K \cap R) = N(a\mathcal{O}_K) = a^n$.
Since $aR \subset a\mathcal{O}_K \cap R$ and $N(aR) = a^n$, $a\mathcal{O}_K \cap R = aR$ as desired.**QED**