# Discriminant and conductor of an order of an algebraic number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $f(X) \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ be a monic irreducible polynomial.
Let $\theta$ be a root of $f(X)$.
Let $A = \mathbb{Z}[\theta]$.
Let $K$ be the field of fractions of $A$.
Let $B$ be the ring of algebraic integers in $K$.
Let $\mathfrak{f}$ be the conductor of $A$, i.e. $\mathfrak{f}$ = {$\alpha \in A; \alpha B \subset A$}.

Is there any relation between the discriminant of $f(X)$ and $\mathfrak{f}$?

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173937/on-the-ring-generated-by-an-algebraic-integer-over-the-ring-of-rational-integers) is a related question.

Answer (score 2):

Let $d$ be the discriminant of $f(X)$.
Let $\mathfrak{D}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}$ be the different.
Then $f'(\theta)B = \mathfrak{f}\mathfrak{D}_{K/\mathbb{Q}}$ (e.g. Neukirch, Ch. III, Th. 2.5).
Taking norms of the both sides, we get $|d| = N(\mathfrak{f})|D|$, where $D$ is the discriminant of $K$.