# Criteria for the normality of a certain localization of an order of an algebraic number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $f(X) \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ be a monic irreducible polynomial.
Let $\theta$ be a root of $f(X)$.
Let $A = \mathbb{Z}[\theta]$.
Let $K$ be the field of fractions of $A$.
Let $p$ be a prime number.
Suppose $p$ divides the discriminat of $f(X)$.
Let $A_p$ be the localization of $A$ with respect to $S = \mathbb{Z} - p\mathbb{Z}$.

Are there any criteria to assure that $A_p$ is integrally closed?

**Motivation**
Combining with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173937/on-the-ring-generated-by-an-algebraic-integer-over-the-ring-of-rational-integers), maybe we can get criteria to assure that $A$ is integrally closed, i.e. it is the ring of algebraic integers in $K$.

Comment: Sufficient conditions will do.

Comment: This is a related question.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174008/normality-of-a-certain-localization-of-an-order-of-an-algebraic-number-field