# Classification of prime ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(f(X))$

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ be the ring of polynomials in one variable.
Let $f(X) \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ be a monic irreducible polynomial.
Let $A = \mathbb{Z}[X]/(f(X))$.
Let $\theta$ = $X$ (mod $f(X)$).

My question: Is the following proposition correct? If yes, how would you prove this?

**Proposition**
Let $P$ be a non-zero prime ideal of $A$.
Then the following assertions hold.

(1) $P$ contains a prime number $p$.

(2) One of the following two cases occurs.

a. If $f(X)$ is irreducible mod $p$, then $P = (p)$.

b. If $f(X)$ is not irreducible mod $p$, then $P = (p, g(\theta))$, where $g(X)$ is an irreducible factor of $f(X)$ mod $p$.

(3) $P$ is a maximal ideal and $A/P$ is a finite field of characteristic $p$.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174595/classification-of-prime-ideals-of-mathbbzx) is a related question.

Comment: When you say "(1) $P$ contains a prime ideal $p$", what do you mean? This statement has no content-it is always trivially true with $P=p$.

Comment: I meant $P$ contains a prime number $p$.
I'll edit it later.

Answer (score 9):

Let us denote by $P$ the corresponding ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ as well. It will contain polynomials that are not multiples of $f(X)$. Let $g(X)$ be one such. Because $f(X)$ is irreducible, the greatest common divisor (in the Euclidean domain $\mathbb{Q}[X]$) must be equal to 1. By Bezout's identity there exist polynomials $u(X),v(X)\in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ such that
$$
u(X)f(X)+v(X)g(X)=1.
$$
Multiplying this by the least common multiple $m$ of the denominators of the coefficients of $u(X)$ and $v(X)$ we see that there exists polynomials $U(X)=mu(X),V(X)=mv(X)\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ such that
$$
m=U(x)f(X)+V(X)g(X)\in P.
$$
So the ideal $P$ contains non-zero integer constants. Because $P$ is a prime ideal, the intersection $P\cap\mathbb{Z}$ is also a (non-zero) prime ideal, and hence it contains a prime number $p$. Because $P$ is non-trivial, $p$ is the only prime number in
$P$. Part (1) is settled.

From  (1) we deduce that the quotient ring $A/P$ is finite. As $A$ is an integral domain, and $P$ is a prime ideal, the ring $A/P$ is also an integral domain. A finite integral domain is always a field, so (3) is proven.

Clearly $A/P$ is generated (as a ring) by $\theta$. So $A/P=\mathbb{F}_p[\theta]$, where I again abuse notation and denote $X+P$ also with $\theta$. Let $g(X)\in\mathbb{F}_p[X]$ be the minimal polynomial of $\theta$ over the prime field. Obviously $g(X)\mid \overline{f}(X)$, where $\overline{f}(X)$ stands for the reduction of $f(X)$ modulo $p$. The claim (2) follows from this relatively easily.

Comment: This is the best, most succinct treatment I've see. Thanks.

Comment: A wonderful proof!!!

Comment: I don't understand this part of your proof "Clearly $A/P$ is generated (as a ring) by $X \; \text{mod} \; f$. So $A/P = \mathbb{F}_p[(X \; \text{mod} \; f) + P]$". Please elaborate. Thank you.

Comment: @VincentJ.Ruan: $A$ is a quotient ring of $R=\Bbb{Z}[X]$. The ring $R$ is generated by $X$, so $A$ is generated by the image of $X$ under the projection $R\to A$. Ditto for the quotient ring $A/P$ that is a homomorphic image of $R$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : So, in your proof, it should be "$A$ is generated as a ring by $X \; \text{mod} \; f$ ...", right?

Comment: @VincentJ.Ruan If it holds for $A$ it holds for $A/P$, by the usual abuse of notation.

Answer (score 8):

You may want to read [this](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CEgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ma.utexas.edu%2Fusers%2Fvoloch%2FHomework%2Fzx.pdf&ei=TIEOULbfHKi80QWn_IDwDQ&usg=AFQjCNHiprFOdpYWi8vM_QnuHaK0upaHfg&sig2=aLNduab9_pawMd-n0a4oaQ) , or  [also this](http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CEoQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fminhyongkim.files.wordpress.com%2F2011%2F10%2Fmaxideal.pdf&ei=TIEOULbfHKi80QWn_IDwDQ&usg=AFQjCNEEGw-fzkwokdGCBMTEOzVIc41a3w&sig2=OjyQciemGy0xfPRhJ9f7yQ) .

Basically and bottom line, a maximal ideal in $\,\Bbb Z[x]\,$ is of the form $\,(p,f(x))\,$ , with $\,p\,$ a prime number and $\,f(x)\,$ an irreducible polynomial when reduced modulo $\,p\,$, i.e. *in* $\,\left(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z\right)[x]\,$