# Classification of primary ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(f(X))$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Carry on with [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174595/classification-of-prime-ideals-of-mathbbzx), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/174605) I have the following question.

Let $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ be the ring of polynomials in one variable, $f(X)\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ be a monic irreducible polynomial, $A = \mathbb{Z}[X]/(f(X))$ and $\theta$ = $X$ (mod $f(X)$). Can we classify all the primary ideals of $A$?

a. If a prime ideal $P$ of $A$ is principal then $P$-primary ideals are prime power.

b. If $P=(p, g(\theta))$ (see, [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/174605)) then can we describe $P$-primary ideals in this case?

Comment: The question was posted on [mathoverflow.se]: [Classification of primary ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(f(X))$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/344747).