# Classification of primary ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+d)$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

To simplify my question posted at [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3408247) and later on at [2](https://mathoverflow.net/q/344747), I repost my question here by changing arbitrary polynomial by a quadratic one.

Let $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ be the ring of polynomials in one variable, $X^2+d\in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ be an irreducible polynomial, $A = \mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+d)$ and $x$ = $X$ (mod $X^2+d$). Can we classify all the primary ideals of $A$?

$(a)$. If a prime ideal $P$ of $A$ is principal then $P$-primary ideals are a prime power.

$(b)$. If $P=(p, x-a)$ where $p$ is a prime integer and $X-a$ is a factor of $X^2+d$ mod $p$ (e.g. see [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/174605)), then can we describe $P$-primary ideals in this case?

Through the back to back discussion in the comments section of [2](https://mathoverflow.net/q/344747),  [David Lampert](https://mathoverflow.net/users/59248/david-lampert) helped me to catch up on primary ideals of $A$ when $d=4$. Indeed, in this case, the only non-principal prime ideal is $M=(2, x)$ and we located the all possible indispensable $M$-primary ideals, I mentioning in the following list.

$(1)$. $2^{n+1}A$

$(2)$. $(2^n\cdot x)A$

$(3)$. $2^nM$

$(4)$. $2^n(2+x)A$

$(5)$. $2^n(2-x)A$

$(6)$. $2^n(4, 2+x)$

where $n\geq 0$.

**My try:** Prime ideals of $A$ are either $pA$ or $(p, x-a)$ where $p$ is a prime integer and $x-a$ is a factor of $X^2+d$ mod $p$, i.e. $a^2\equiv -d$ mod $p$. In the first case primary ideals are prime power. Let $P=(p, x-a)$.
For $p=2$ the prime ideal is either $P=(2, x)$ ($d$ is even) or $P=(2, x+1)$ ($d$ is odd).

In the first case $P^2=2P$. If $d$ is the power of $2$ then primary ideals are the same as listed above. If $d$ is not a power of $2$ then $P$-primary ideals are the following ones.

$(1)$. $2^{n+1}A$

$(2)$. $2^nP$

where $n\geq 0$.