# Are $k[x^2,x^3+x]$ and $k[x^3,x^2+x]$ UFD's?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

It is well-known that $R=k[x^2,x^3]$ is not a UFD, since $x^2x^2x^2=x^3x^3$ are two different decompositions of $x^6$ to irreducibles.

> **Question 1:** Are $A=k[x^2,x^3+x]$ and $B=k[x^3,x^2+x]$ UFD's?

It seems to me that they are, but I have not found a proof (or a counterexample).

> **Question 2:** If $A$ and $B$ are UFD's, is it because one of the generators ($x^3+x$ or $x^2+x$) is separable (=have different roots)? In $R$ both generators are not separable.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are these rings integrally closed?

Comment: @AnginaSeng, thank you for your comment. Did you hint that they are not integrally closed (and hence not UFD's)?

Comment: What are their fields of fractions?

Comment: $A=k[x^2,x^3+x] \subset k[x]$ with $x$ satisfying $T^2-x^2$, so $x$ is integral over $A$ but not in $A$. However, I suspect (but maybe I am wrong) that the field of fractions of $A$ is strictly smaller than $k(x)$.

Comment: Could the field of fractions of $A$ be strictly between $k(x^2)$ and $k(x)$?

Comment: @AnginaSeng, oh, you are right..The field of fractions of $A$, $F(A)$, satisfies $k(x^2) \subsetneq F(A) \subseteq k(x)$, hence $F(A)=k(x)$, by considerations of degrees of field extensions.

Comment: @AnginaSeng, thank you for the hints. You can write your idea as an answer, if you like.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2808373/for-which-f-g-in-kt-kf-g-is-integrally-closed/2808521#2808521

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $A$, write $f = x^2, g = x^3 + x$. Then we have

$$g^2 = (x^3 + x)^2 = x^2 (x^2 + 1)^2 = f(f + 1)^2.$$

In $B$, similarly write $f = x^3, g = x^2 + x$. Then we have

$$g^3 = (x^2 + x)^3 = x^3 (x^3 + 3x^2 + 3x + 1) = f(f + 3g + 1).$$

Probably a more geometric approach is possible that would give some conditions under which $k[f, g]$ isn't a UFD.

Comment: Very nice, thank you! I wonder if it is possible to 'find' all $u=u(x), v=v(x) \in k[x]$ such that $k[u,v]$ is a UFD and $\dim(k[u,v])=1$ (namely, $k \subsetneq k[u,v]$).

Comment: Of course, if $u=v$ with $\deg(u) \geq 1$, then trivially $k[u,v]=k[u,u]=k[u]$ is isomorphic to $k[x]$, hence a UFD.

Comment: By A-M-S (Abhyankar-Moh-Suzuki) theorem: If $\deg(u),\deg(v) \geq 2$ and $\gcd(\deg(u),\deg(v))=1$, then $k[u,v] \subsetneq k[x]$. I wonder if in such a situation (two relatively prime degrees, each degree is strictly bigger than $1$), $k[u,v]$ is necessarily not a UFD? (perhaps the above idea of not being integrally closed can be applied?). Thank you.

Comment: Is $k[x^2+x,x^3+x]$ a UFD? What is its field of fractions? If it is a UFD then my claim in the previous comment is wrong.

Comment: @user237522  Let's assume $k$ is algebraically closed to make our lives simple. If $A\subseteq k[x]$ is a UFD of dimension $1$ then one gets a dominant map $\mathbb{A}^1\to U$ where $U:=\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is a smooth integral curve. This then extends to a dominant map $\mathbb{P}^1\to X$ where $X$ the smooth compactification of $A$. This implies that $X\cong\mathbb{P}^1$. So then, one has that $U$ looks like the complement of a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^1_k$. Thus, $U$ should be isomorphic to $k[t,\frac{1}{t-a_1},\ldots,\frac{1}{t-a_n}]$ for some $a_i$. etc.

Comment: @AlexYoucis, thank you very much! You can write your comment as another answer, if you like. Unfortunately, I still know very little about algebraic geometry, so could not understand your comment. Please, what is the relation between the original ring $A$ and $U$?

Comment: @AlexYoucis, please another question: Is it possible to adjust the ideas in your comment to $S \subseteq k[x,y]$ a UFD of dimension $2$? Thank you.

Comment: @user237522 Not that I can see. Curve was leveraged at several points during what I said. In particular, there's no reason that you can extend your map to a map $\mathbb{P}^2$ to a compactification of $\mathrm{Spec}(S)$.

Comment: @user237522 In fact, to be clear I think that my comment shows above that $A\cong k[t]$. So, $A$ must be generated by a single element in $k[t]$.