# Is $k[x^2+x,x^3+x]$ a UFD?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

Let $u=u(x)=x^2+x$, $v=v(x)=x^3+x$ be two elements of $k[x]$, $k$ is a field of characteristic zero.

> Is $R=k[x^2+x,x^3+x]$ a UFD?

**Remark:**
It is well-known that $k[x^2,x^3]$ is not a UFD, since $x^2x^2x^2=x^3x^3$ are two different decompositions of $x^6$ to irreducibles.

Also see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3813423/are-kx2-x3x-and-kx3-x2x-ufds/3813443#3813443) slightly similar question.

I do not know if $R$ is integrally closed (in its field of fractions $F(R)=k(x^2+x,x^3+x)$)?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Doesn't my answer to your question from 2 years ago resolve this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2808373/for-which-f-g-in-kt-kf-g-is-integrally-closed/2808521#2808521 KReiser has given you basically the same answer below.

Comment: @RichardD.James, thank you for your comment and previous answer.

Comment: @RichardD.James I'm embarrassed to admit I did not see this duplicate before writing my answer. I think you are correct that your answer to that question addresses this question as well, and I'm marking this question as a duplicate of that one. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @KReiser Certainly no need for embarrassment! It's reassuring to see someone else take the same approach. Plus the questions of being a UFD vs just integrally closed are different, as you point out in your last sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to understanding when a ring of the form $k[p(t),q(t)]$ for two nonconstant polynomials $p(t),q(t)$ is a UFD is that such a ring is the coordinate algebra of a 1-dimensional affine curve in $\Bbb A^2_k$. This means that $k[p(t),q(t)]\cong k[x,y]/(f(x,y))$ for some polynomial $f(x,y)$. Such a ring is a UFD if and only if it's normal and has vanishing class group. In particular, if $V(f)$ isn't normal, it can't be a UFD.

To explain why $k[p(t),q(t)]\cong k[x,y]/(f)$, we can eliminate $t$ from the system $\{x-p(t),y-q(t)\}$ to get a single relation between $x$ and $y$: this will be our $f$. In our case, we can use the resultant to do this and get $$k[t^2+t,t^3+t]\cong k[x,y]/(x^3+2x^2-3xy+2x-y^2-2y).$$ From here, we look to verify that $V(f)$ is smooth, as any normal curve is smooth.

To check smoothness, we compute the partial derivatives: $$\frac{df}{dx} = 3x^2+4x-3y+2$$ $$\frac{df}{dy} = -3x-2y-2$$

and doing some light algebra, we see that after setting each of these equal to zero, we have two solutions: $(-2,2)$ and $(\frac{-5}{6},\frac14)$. Plugging in to our original equation, we see that $(-2,2)$ is on our curve (it's given by $t=\frac{-1\pm \sqrt{-7}}2$), so we see that our curve is singular. As normal curves are smooth, we see that our curve isn't normal, so $k[t^2+t,t^3+t]$ cannot be a UFD.

---

If we had instead found that our ring was integrally closed in it's field of fractions, we'd have more work to do: we'd have to compute the class group and check if that vanished or not.

Comment: Some friendly advice: from looking through your question history, it seems like you have been trying to solve something related to or some particular case of the Jacobian conjecture via asking a bunch of questions on MSE for a fair amount of the past 5 years. Given how long this conjecture has stood (~81 years as of the time of writing) and how many false proofs have been given, you may wish to consider better ways of spending your time.